# Magento - add common supplier information in product description (static block?)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-manufacturer

I have a magento website (1.9.2) and I have various products from various suppliers. I want to add the information of the supplier on every product's description. That information will be a logo, some contact details etc.

Is it possible to generate a static block for each supplier and include it in each of his product's description?

Is there any more "automated" / "proper" way to do this? Like having a list of suppliers/manufacturers and have a field in the product that points there and their info is automatically included in the product's description?

Any hints & tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible way to achieve this:

**Option 1:** Create Suppliers attribute and assign to each products. Using suppliers name create static block for each supplier that contain the supplier Logo and contact details.

On the Product details page fetch the products assigned supplier and using the name as static block ID, include static block on product detail page like below:

`$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(strtolower($supplierName))->toHtml()`

**Option 2:** You can install shop by brands extension that provide complete separate module to manage brands. like below:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-brands-by-zeon-solutions.html

then using the extension function you need to fetch brand (supplier) information on product details page.

I prefer to use Option 1 if you don't provide Shop by brand option in frontend.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably go with option 1 to have more flexibility :)